# Counting number times a particular value is repeated in a C# list

Tags: c#, excel, list, oledb

I have a list with 7 columns in it with several rows of data which are imported from an Excel sheet using Oledb. Now I wanted to go through the list and from column 1 and check the value in first row of first column and find out how many times it occurs in the list and if it occurs more than once I would like to store all the other column values along with the first column in another list for some operations on it

For Example I have the following rows of data in the list

```
Time        CC   Month  prc      str    tx      qq
14:46:00    NP  14-Dec                 4.0000   6,000
14:46:00    LN  14-Dec  6.00    Put     2.0090  1,500
14:46:00    LN  14-Dec  6.00    Call    0.0095  1,500
14:42:57    LN  14-Sep  3.85    Put     0.0860  50
14:42:57    LN  14-Sep  3.85    Call    0.1200  50
14:34:00    LN  14-Sep  3.25    Put     0.0025  200
14:34:00    LN  14-Sep  3.50    Put     0.0100  100
14:32:00    NP  14-Dec                  4.0000  2,000
14:32:00    LN  14-Dec  6.00    Put     2.0090  500
14:32:00    LN  14-Dec  6.00    Call    0.0095  500
14:27:00    LN  15-Mar  4.50    Call    0.2230  100
14:26:00    LN  15-Mar  4.50    Call    0.2210  200
```

In the above rows of data in the list I have first column as `time` and in `time` column first row has `14:46:00`, now  would like to check for number times `14:46:00` is repeated and insert all the rows and columns associated with `14:46:00` and perform some arithmetic operation on them and move onto next unique value of time that is `14:42:57` and repeat the process

Example List1 for `Time 14:46:00`  would be as follows

```
14:46:00    NP  14-Dec                  4.0000  6,000
14:46:00    LN  14-Dec  6.00    Put     2.0090  1,500
14:46:00    LN  14-Dec  6.00    Call    0.0095  1,500
```

Once Some operation are done on the above list it can be overwritten by next set of values for `time 14:42:57`

I have imported Data from Excel Sheet to list using following lines of code

```
var fileName = string.Format("{0}\\AxiomParser.xlsx", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());

            var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;", fileName);

            var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] ", connectionString);
            var ds = new DataSet();

            adapter.Fill(ds, "axiomData");

            DataTable data = ds.Tables["axiomData"];


            List<DataRow> listAxiomData = data.AsEnumerable().ToList();
            List<AxiomDS> resultAxiomData = new List<AxiomDS>();

            foreach (var row in listAxiomData)
            {
                var entries = new AxiomDS();
                entries.time = Convert.ToDateTime(row[0]);
                entries.CC = row[1].ToString();
                entries.term = row[2].ToString();
                if (row[3].ToString() != "")
                {
                    entries.strike = Convert.ToDouble(row[3]);
                }

                entries.strategy = row[4].ToString();

                if (row[5].ToString() != "")
                {
                    entries.price = Convert.ToDouble(row[5]);
                }
                entries.quantity = Convert.ToInt32(row[6]);

                resultAxiomData.Add(entries);
            }
```

Comment: So, you want to group values by Column1, don't you? I'm not sure, but I think you say that this is all about grouping.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class AxiomDS
{
    public DateTime time { get; set; }
    public string CC { get; set; }
    public string term { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<AxiomDS> resultAxiomData = new List<AxiomDS>();

        var uniqueTimes = resultAxiomData.Select(a => a.time).Distinct();

        foreach (var uniqueTime in uniqueTimes)
        {
            // Find all records that have this time
            var recordsToProcess = resultAxiomData.Where(r => r.time == uniqueTime);

            // TODO:
            foreach (var record in recordsToProcess)
            {
                // Do something with this list
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, The inner `foreach` could be a select statement that builds the `AxiomDS` objects.

Comment: Yes, it sure could!  There are lots of ways to approach this problem with LINQ or otherwise.

Comment: @Mangist How to retrieve each column from "record" and add them to a list?

Comment: Use your code you wrote above: List<DataRow> listAxiomData = data.AsEnumerable().ToList();
            List<AxiomDS> resultAxiomData = new List<AxiomDS>();

            foreach (var row in listAxiomData)
            {
                var entries = new AxiomDS();
                entries.time = Convert.ToDateTime(row[0]);
                entries.CC = row[1].ToString();
                entries.term = row[2].ToString();
                if (row[3].ToString() != "")
                {
                    entries.strike = Convert.ToDouble(row[3]);
                }

.......

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to group your entries by `time`, and then perform some work on each group that has more than one record. LINQ makes this easy:

```
var groupedData = from result in resultAxiomData
                  group result by result.time into resultGroup
                  where resultGroup.Count() > 1
                  order by resultGroup.Key
                  select resultGroup;
```

Now you can loop over the grouped results:

```
foreach (var timeGroup in groupedData)
{
    // timeGroup.Key is the time
    foreach (var entry in timeGroup)
    {
        // process the entry
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ-to-objects:

```
public class Row {
    DateTime Time {get; set;}
    string CC { get; set; }
    string Month {get; set;}
    double PRC {get; set;}
    string Str {get; set;}
    double TX {get; set;}
    int QQ { get; set; }
}

var allEntries = new List<Row>();

//Load data...

var allEntriesDict = allEntries.Select(entry => entry.Time)
                               .Distinct()
                               .ToDictionary(time => time, 
                                             time => allEntries.Where(entry => entry.Time == time).ToList());
foreach(var kvp in allEntriesDictionary) {
    //kvp.Key is the Time
    //kvp.Value is a List<Row>
    DoCalculations(kvp.Value);
}
```